# Graph query: is it possible to retrieve a RefinableStrings or Set of terms starting from a list column name?

Tags: search, sharepoint-rest-api, managed-property, microsoft-graph, refiner

As stated in the question title, if I have a column in a SharePoint list named "Category", and associated it to a Refinable String, let's say `RefinableString03`, is it possible to retrieve via Graph or REST API the `RefinableString` or the Set of terms, having the column name?

Thanks in advance.